# How can I change a file name without changing the file type?

Tags: php, file, upload

How, in php, can I change the file name of an upload without changing the file type?

Comment: You need to explain what you mean.

Comment: @Toby I interpreted the question as "if you upload a file, how do you change the file name on the local system"

Answer (score 3):

You can use [pathinfo](http://php.net/pathinfo):

```
$actual_filename = basename($_FILES['myfile']['name']);
$extension = pathinfo($actual_filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$new_filename = "foo.{$extension}";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], "/target/path/{$new_filename}")) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I think that's what he means.

Answer (score 0):

php has a `move_uploaded_file` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 0):

before actually renaming it you should get the extension from the filename and than add it after the new name.

```
<?php
$ext = substr(strrchr($fileName, '.'), 1);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check first of all this offical tutorial 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php